# View wont update even $apply is called

Tags: html, angularjs, model-view-controller

The code I have written is as follows

```
$scope.update=function(){

    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            $scope.fav_legs_data=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("hw_leg"));
            $scope.fav_comm_data=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("hw_comm"));
            $scope.fav_bill_data=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("hw_bill"));
        });
    }, 0, false);
}
```

When the user clicks a button update is called using `ng-click="update()"`

Is there some thing wrong that I am doing or What is the correct way to update the view dynamically.

I have also viewed the question at [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16185753/angular-js-model-update-doesnt-trigger-view-update#) and tried to use that but no results.

The full code is as follows

```
app.controller('fav_ctrl',function($scope,$http,$timeout){
$scope.fav_legs_data=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("hw_leg"));
$scope.fav_comm_data=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("hw_comm"));
$scope.fav_bill_data=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("hw_bill"));
$scope.update=function(){    
    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            $scope.fav_legs_data=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("hw_leg"));
            $scope.fav_comm_data=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("hw_comm"));
            $scope.fav_bill_data=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("hw_bill"));
            alert("I have updated");
            console.log($scope.fav_legs_data);
        });
    }, 0, false);
}
}
```

and the HTML code is as follows

```
<div id="sidebar-wrapper">
  <ul class="sidebar-nav" ng-controller="fav_ctrl">
    <li id="legis_menu" class="sidebar-brand">
      <a href="">
        <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> Legislators
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="bills_menu" class="sidebar-brand">
      <a href="">
        <i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i> Bills
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="comm_menu" class="sidebar-brand">
      <a href="">
        <i class="fa fa-file-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Committees
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="favs_menu" ng-click="update()" class="sidebar-brand">
      <a href="">
        <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i> Favorites
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="Bills_k" ng-controller="fav_ctrl" class="tab-pane fade">

                <div style="margin-bottom: 0px;margin-right: 0px; margin-left: 0px;" class="row well well-sm">
                  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="border-collapse:separate;">
                    <h4>Favorite Bills</h4>
                  </div>
                </div>  
                <div class="table-responsive">
                  <table style="border: 1px solid #ccc; border-collapse:separate; border-top: 0px; border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px; padding:15px; padding-top:0px;" class="table table-hover">
                    <tr>
                      <th>

                      </th>
                      <th>
                        Bill ID
                      </th>
                      <th>
                        Bill Type
                      </th>
                      <th>
                        Title
                      </th>
                      <th>
                        Chamber
                      </th>
                      <th>  
                        Introducted on
                      </th>
                      <th>
                        Sponsor
                      </th>
                      <th>

                      </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-repeat="result in fav_bill_data">
                      <td>
                        <button id="bill_fav_button" class="fav_button" ng-click="delb(result.committee_id)">
                          <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true" style="padding: 2px; color: #ccc; font-size: 30px; "></i></button>  
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-transform: uppercase;">
                          {{result.bill_id}}
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-transform: uppercase;">
                          {{result.bill_type}}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          {{result.official_title}}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          {{result.chamber}}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          {{result.introduced_on}}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          {{result.sponsor.title}}. {{result.sponsor.last_name}}, {{result.sponsor.first_name}}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="fvdb(result.bill_id)">View Details</button>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
```

When clicked on the favorites in the side bar menu The div with the id Bills_k is shown to user.

PS . I am using bootstrap

Edit - My entire website can be found at [link](http://pentyala.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/Homework/Aditya.html). When user opens  legislators and chooses a legislator and adds him to his favorites by clicking the star button, this data is stored in the Local Storage of user. When he opens favorites this data has to load.

You can see if the data is saved at your local storage by entering the following command at your console. `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("hw_leg"))`

Comment: Can you share a reproducible example? Why are you using `timeout` and `$apply`? Simply setting the scope values should suffice in most cases

Comment: Yeah I have tried that but it is not working @mparnisari

Comment: this is all kinds of wrong.  first, using `$scope.$apply` is ***rarely ever necessary***.  secondly, `$timeout` triggers a digest automatically, so all this code will do is give you `digest in progress` type errors.  plus,  you haven't shown any example of what these properties are bound to in the HTML, so it's not really obvious why they wouldn't be updating without all the extra function calls.

Comment: and please, don't refer to a question answered 3 years ago with a different version of the framework and question why it didn't work, unless you also show that you are using the same version referenced in the question.  and if that's the case, the first thing you should be doing is updating your framework anyway....  things change quickly in the angular world.

Comment: I have added all the function calls and html code @Claies

Comment: so you have some array of data that you are (somewhere) in your code saving into local storage, and then here you are trying to retrieve it, parse it from a string into `fav_bill_data`, and then use `ng-repeat` to iterate through it.  how are you saving it into local storage, and are you sure that it needs to be parsed from JSON?  what does a `console.log($scope.fav_bill_data)` show after the assignment?  we still need a lot more for this to be considered a [mcve].

Comment: 1) Is there any data in your locale storage keys? 2) You appear to be re-loading the **same data** on click (in a timeout for some reason). Why would you expect it to change anything?

Comment: 3) Your update button is outside the `fav_ctrl` scope so it won't call the `update()` method (at least not the one in `fav_ctrl`)

Comment: also, you appear to be using the same controller for more than one HTML segment.  this isn't a good idea, as each time you use `ng-controller` you are creating a new instance of the controller, and changes in one area of the page won't be reflected in the other section.  either declare the controller higher in the HTML tree, or (better option) declare smaller controllers for specific purposes, following the new angular component style.

Comment: If I had to guess, you are clicking the `update()` in the top `ul` group, and expecting it to update the data that is bound in the lower table, but since these are two different instances of the same controller, the button isn't affecting the data.  The button is adding the data to the controller for the `ul` group, not the instance for the table.

Comment: edited the question @Claies

Comment: How about if I use $rootScope instead of $Scope. This way I can bind the update button and the table @Phil

Comment: you *can* use `$rootScope`, but this is not what `$rootScope` is intended for.  you should favor services over `$rootScope`, for future forward compatibility.

Comment: Okay! Thanks guys for making it more clear of what to use and how to use. I will start from scratch again and make it better this time :)